# Writing a list to a file more efficiently in Racket

Tags: racket

I want to write to a file the numbers from some lists (nested in a big list), e.g. for:

```
'((33 62 42 -19 30)
  (-22 -15 60 -55 24)
  (4 -48 22 -63 5))
```

To output in a text file:

```
33 62 42 -19 30
-22 -15 60 -55 24
4 -48 22 -63 5
```

I've written something that works, but I feel like it's a bit slow. Here's the code:

```
#lang racket

(define lists
  (build-list 100000
              (λ _  (for/list ([i (in-range 5)])
                      (random -100 100)))))

(define (list->file lst path)
  (let loop ([clone lst] [out (open-output-file path #:exists 'replace)])
    (if (empty? clone)
        (close-output-port out)
        (begin
          (for ([i (in-range (length (first clone)))])
            (display (list-ref (first clone) i) out)
            (when (< (+ i 1) (length (first clone))) (display " " out)))
          (unless (empty? (rest clone)) (display "\n" out))
          (loop (rest clone) out)))))

(time (list->file lists "test.txt"))
```

First I just generated a list of 100000 sublists, each with 5 random numbers, then in the `list->file` function I just output for each sublist each number followed by a space then move on recursively to the next sublist. Is there a way to make this more efficiently?

Comment: We discovered that our solutions have quite different performances depending on the version of Racket in use. To decide which one is more "efficient", you'll need to test them in your own environment ;)

Comment: @ÓscarLópez On my computer your solution is the fastest (with about 100-200 ms on average), I tried with some larger datasets too. I like the last part of your answer though that says there's no need for premature optimizations as they're the root of all evil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my machine this is between 50ms - 100ms faster than your solution, preserving the exact same behavior:

```
(define (print-tuple tuple out)
  (cond [(empty? (rest tuple))
         (display (first tuple) out)]
        [else
         (display (first tuple) out)
         (display " " out)
         (print-tuple (rest tuple) out)]))
    
(define (list->file lst path)
  (call-with-output-file* path #:exists 'replace
   (lambda (out)
     (let loop ([clone lst])
       (cond [(empty? (rest clone))
              (print-tuple (first clone) out)]
             [else
              (print-tuple (first clone) out)
              (newline out)
              (loop (rest clone))])))))
```

I replaced the code for accessing the elements in a list using an index for something more idiomatic in Scheme - you should avoid using `list-ref` and `length`, those are expensive operations when working with lists! I also extracted the display logic to its own procedure (we could in-line it to shave a few milliseconds, but it's not worth it). And it's better to use `call-with-output-file*` or `with-output-to-file`, they're simpler because we don't need to explicitly close the output port.

I did a few mini-benchmarks and found that my code is faster than yours and also faster than Sorawee's solution - but it was pretty fast to begin with, so maybe there's no need for premature optimizations, you know they're the root of all evil.

Comment: I'm curious why your program is much faster, so I performed some measurement. It turns out that in my computer, in the Racket CS implementation, yours consistently takes about 250ms, which is slower than mine. On the other hand, in Racket BC implementation, mine takes 170ms and yours takes 160ms.

Comment: That's strange, in my computer your version takes the same time as OP's, and I assume I'm running BC. What's the difference between CS and BC that could explain this discrepancy?

Comment: I don't know, but I agree that this is indeed strange.

Answer (score 0):

I measure the time that your program runs. It's about 300ms, which is really fast already. How long do you expect it to take? Why do you think it is inefficient? Without a concrete objective or evidence that this is the bottleneck of your application, it's just a premature optimization.

Also, if performance really matters in your application, perhaps Racket might not the best fit. Racket (implementation) is not slow, but it's not aimed to be incredibly fast.

In any case, if I were to write this program, I would write it like this:

```
#lang racket

(define lists
  (build-list 100000
              (λ _  (for/list ([i (in-range 5)])
                      (random -100 100)))))

(define (list->file lst path)
  (with-output-to-file path #:exists 'replace
    (λ ()
      (for ([line (in-list lst)])
        (for ([e (in-list line)] [i (in-naturals)])
          (unless (zero? i) (display " "))
          (display e))
        (newline)))))

(time (list->file lists "test.txt"))
```

This program takes about 230ms to run, so it is faster than yours by about 70ms. I haven't carefully measured what causes the difference, but one thing I want to point out is that `length` and `list-ref` is a  linear time operation, so we usually want to avoid them. However, for a list of fixed, small size (length 5), it should be fine.

Comment: Minor comments: it's a matter of personal preference, but I think using `in-indexed` would be more elegant in this case. Also, to exactly replicate OP's output, the last line shouldn't have a line break.